# How do I move objects randomly on a single axis with geometry nodes?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, axis

I am trying to make a wall with lego bricks, and I am trying to move each one slightly differently on the Y axis so it looks more realistic. However, I am lost as to how you can do this. Here is a screenshot of my current node set up:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this (so you were pretty close). Geometry nodes is a bit confusing at the beginning, but the longer you are doing it there quicker you will get ;)

[image]

sorry, i thought you meant rotation. Here the node setup for the movement:

[image]